# Comparação entre números decimais

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho 2 posts numa tabela, com os preços 500,00 e 88,98. Quando eu executo para ordenar de acordo com o maior preço, o Mysql me retorna que o 88,98 é maior que o 500,00, o campo "preço" é uma string, por que isso acontece?

Comment: Consegue colocar o código que você fez?

Comment: E porque `preço` é `varchar`?

Answer (score 2):

Porque 5 vem antes do 8, como é string ele está comparando os caracteres. Mude para decimal o tipo de dado.

Comment: Para qual tipo? mudei para decimal e tive isso: Truncated DECIMAL value '5,00'

Answer (score 2):

Tu podes seguir o que Douglas disse, apartir da extrutura da tabela trocar o tipo de dado para este campo. Como tambem tu podes converter apartir do select ao buscar os dados usando esta sintaxe:

```
SELECT seu_campo FROM `sua_tabela`
ORDER BY CONVERT(seu_campo ,DECIMAL(10,2)) ASC
;
```

Comment: Obrigado, irei testar, mas o que seria este 10,2?

Comment: 10,2 são os atributos do tipo de dado decimal. Onde:
10-Representa os números antes da virgula
2-Representa os números apos a virgula (casa decimais)
poderias ter por um numero por exemplo: 100000000,25